# Way to iterate through both persisted AND non-persisted children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There must a way to do this that I'm missing. Say I have...

```
Category
  has_many :products

Product
  belongs_to :category
```

Now I build a number of new children in memory (say inside a form object) like this:

```
category.products.build(name: "blah blah", etc...)
```

Using **.each** calls ActiveRecord and only iterates through persisted children

```
category.products.each do |product|
```

Is there a way to iterate through **ALL** children, no matter if they are in memory or saved in the DB? And keep any **.order** clause in effect too??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not reloading the category somehow between building the products and iterating over them? Just did a quick test and this seems to work as you intend it to (other model names, same associations):

```
2.5.1 :018 > c = Channel.first
  Channel Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "channels".* FROM "channels" ORDER BY "channels"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Channel id: 1> 
2.5.1 :019 > c.channel_users.build
 => #<ChannelUser id: nil, enabled: nil, status: nil, last_grant_at: nil, channel_id: 1> 
2.5.1 :020 > c.channel_users.each { |cu| p cu }
  ChannelUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "channel_users".* FROM "channel_users" WHERE "channel_users"."channel_id" = ?  [["channel_id", 1]]
#<ChannelUser id: 1, enabled: nil, status: "blocking", last_grant_at: "2018-09-15 18:32:04", channel_id: 1>
#<ChannelUser id: nil, enabled: nil, status: nil, last_grant_at: nil, channel_id: 1>
```

Comment: Ah shoot -- you are correct. I just did a similar test and realized that I bungled my question. Sorry! I am trying to kill a N+! query and need to do this to do that: category.products.includes(:inventory).each do |product| and it's the .includes that causes only persisted records to be iterated. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You could keep track of the new record separately (it's returned from the `.build`), convert the persisted records into an array (`category.products.includes(:inventory).to_a`) and then append the new record to that array.  Which you should be able to use just like the loop you're doing otherwise.

Comment: Hmmm yeah, that's a good idea and I guess treating them that way is the only way. Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: I looked and haven't found any good way around it. Seems like chaining AR query methods will always cause the relation to be loaded from DB only.